# Android studio - MainActivity.kt cant access id

Tags: android, kotlin

cant access id attribute in the mainActivity.kt
i have tried :
1. clean project on the build menu
2. rebuild project on the build menu
3. FILE-> invalidate cache and restart

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/decidebtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="Decide!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    decidebtn.setOnClickListener{

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**It's deprecated Base on the [google document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)**

Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported.

Use `View Binding` instead of Kotlin synthetic

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access widget in code then you need to enable databinding in build.gradle file :

```
 dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

you need to define layout tag in XMl and following code in JAVA:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add in `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then import layout package in MainActivity file

Yes, kotlin synthetics is deprecated but still it is good enough in a small project

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import your XML file (XML path.activity_main*)